# Spring Jackson Mapper

Tags: spring, mapping, jackson

Just wondering if is it possible to ask mapper not to serialize certain fields if user is in certain role. Meaning security config will control views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `@JsonIgnore` on the hidden properties

Comment: This would hide the fields from all users, not only from those with a certain role.

Comment: if user is in certain role. Meaning security config will control views